# Exception: partition is not a recognized option, when creating a kafka topic inside a docker.

Tags: apache-kafka, docker-compose

I just start working with Kafka-docker. And I'm taring to create a topic with the following command inside the docker:

```
./kafka-topics.sh --create --zookeeper zoo1:2181 --replication-factor 3 --partition 2 --topic test
```

It guive me the following error:

```
Exception in thread "main" joptsimple.UnrecognizedOptionException: partition is not a recognized option
    at joptsimple.OptionException.unrecognizedOption(OptionException.java:108)
    at joptsimple.OptionParser.handleLongOptionToken(OptionParser.java:510)
    at joptsimple.OptionParserState$2.handleArgument(OptionParserState.java:56)
    at joptsimple.OptionParser.parse(OptionParser.java:396)
    at kafka.admin.TopicCommand$TopicCommandOptions.<init>(TopicCommand.scala:340)
    at kafka.admin.TopicCommand$.main(TopicCommand.scala:43)
    at kafka.admin.TopicCommand.main(TopicCommand.scala)
```

I have add the following lines in the hosts file:

```
 127.0.0.1     kafka1
 127.0.0.1     zoo1
```

Answer (score 16, accepted):

It's not `--partition`, but `--partitions`

Answer (score 0):

```
kafka-topics.bat --create --topic my-first-topic -zookeeper localhost:2181 --replication-factor 1 --partitions 3.
```

Hey Boss this is windows for creating topic so i observed your command using docker overall command is correct only [partition]is spelling wrong instead of [partitions]