# Exception in thread "main" joptsimple.UnrecognizedOptionException: zookeeper is not a recognized option

Tags: apache-kafka

I am new to kafka and zookepper, and I am trying to create a topic, but I am getting this error -

```
Exception in thread "main" joptsimple.UnrecognizedOptionException: zookeeper is not a recognized option
        at joptsimple.OptionException.unrecognizedOption(OptionException.java:108)
        at joptsimple.OptionParser.handleLongOptionToken(OptionParser.java:510)
        at joptsimple.OptionParserState$2.handleArgument(OptionParserState.java:56)
        at joptsimple.OptionParser.parse(OptionParser.java:396)
        at kafka.admin.TopicCommand$TopicCommandOptions.<init>(TopicCommand.scala:517)
        at kafka.admin.TopicCommand$.main(TopicCommand.scala:47)
        at kafka.admin.TopicCommand.main(TopicCommand.scala)
```

I am using this command to create the topic -

```
.\bin\windows\kafka-topics.bat --create --zookeeper localhost:2181 --replication-factor 1 --partions 1 --topic TestTopic
```

Comment: Anyone who is installing Kafka using this article is going to face this issue. https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-apache-kafka-on-ubuntu-18-04

Answer (score 154, accepted):

Newer versions(2.2+) of Kafka no longer requires ZooKeeper connection string

`--zookeeper localhost:2181`

It throws the following exception while creating a topic

> Exception in thread "main" joptsimple.UnrecognizedOptionException:
> zookeeper is not a recognized option

Instead, add Kafka Broker `--bootstrap-server localhost:9092` connection string.

```
./kafka-topics.sh --create --topic test-topic --bootstrap-server localhost:9092 --replication-factor 1 --partitions 4
```

Comment: In my case in windows, it worked: kafka-topics.bat --create --topic test-topic --bootstrap-server localhost:9092 --replication-factor 1 --partitions 1

Comment: kafka-topics.bat --bootstrap-server localhost:9092 --list ( for listing the topics )

Answer (score 11):

In the latest version kafka_2.12-3.1.0 (2022) after unzipping and setting the properties and logs. keep the Kafka folder on the C drive and always run the command prompt with 'run as administrator'.
The .bat file is for windows

Terminal 1

> C:\kafka\bin\windows>zookeeper-server-start.bat
> ..\..\config\zookeeper.properties

Terminal 2

> C:\kafka\bin\windows>kafka-server-start.bat
> ..\..\config\server.properties

Terminal 3

> C:\kafka\bin\windows>kafka-topics.bat --create --topic tutorialspedia
> --bootstrap-server localhost:9092

> `Created topic tutorialspedia.`

To checklist of topic created

> C:\kafka\bin\windows>kafka-topics.bat --list --bootstrap-server
> localhost:9092
>
> `tutorialspedia`

Answer (score 3):

Read the [official Kafka documentation for the version you downloaded](https://kafka.apache.org/30/documentation.html#quickstart), and not some other blog/article that you might have copied the command from

`zookeeper` is almost never used for CLI commands in current versions

If you run `bin\kafka-topics` on its own with `--help` or no options, then it'll print the help messaging that shows all available arguments.

Answer (score 1):

It's not `--partions`, but `--partitions` (typo).
Same like you, see this link: [Exception: partition is not a recognized option, when creating a kafka topic inside a docker.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47370145/exception-partition-is-not-a-recognized-option-when-creating-a-kafka-topic-ins)

Answer (score 1):

Kafka Created Topics for Windows:

```
kafka-topics.bat --create --topic learningkafka --bootstrap-server localhost:9092
```

After topic created we can check the kafka list:

```
kafka-topics.bat --list --bootstrap-server localhost:9092
```

Answer (score 0):

Kakfa create Topic :

```
./kafka-topics.sh --create --topic test-topic --bootstrap-server localhost:9092 --replication-factor 1 --partitions 4
```